# Laravel php artisan migrate: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, laravel, class, model, migration

I'm actually building a simple web app based on Laravel.
I've created a Model Card and wanted to add a migration for this one.
When I run command: 'php artisan migrate' i get an error

```
 SQLSTATE\[42S02\]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table      'agenda.migrations' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: select\<\\migration from migrations order by batch asc,migration asc)

at vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:822
818▕                     $this-\>getName(), $query, $this-\>prepareBindings($bindings), $e
819▕                 );
820▕             }
821▕
➜ 822▕             throw new QueryException(
823▕                 $this-\>getName(), $query, $this-\>prepareBindings($bindings), $e
824▕             );
825▕         }
826▕     }
```

So i tried to run php artisan migrate:install to create my migration table and it works.But when i run php artisan migrate again it drops migrations table.

I've also tried: php artisan migrate:reset and php artisan migrate:rollback

Here is my Card class code

```
<?php

namespace App\\Models;

use Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Factories\\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model;

class Card extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
public string $title;
public string $description;
}
```

There my migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migration;
use Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
/\*\*
\* Run the migrations.
\*/
public function up(): void
{
Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table-\>id();
$table-\>timestamps();
});
}

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cards');
    }

};
```

I have nothing in boot function on AppServiceProvider.php

How can I solve this problem?
Edit boot function ?? Run a special command?

Comment: Check php artisan migrate:refresh